# How to set the cursor focus after toggling the NERDTree in vim?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

By default I have turned off the NERDTree and I use `F2` to toggle it.

```
" autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
" autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
nmap <silent> <special> <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<RETURN>
```

After turning on the NERDTree by pressing `F2`, the cursor is then focused on the NERDTree window. My question is how to redesign the `F2` shortcut so the focus window NOT to the NERDTree window?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
nnoremap <silent> <special> <F2> :NERDTreeToggle <Bar> if &filetype ==# 'nerdtree' <Bar> wincmd p <Bar> endif<CR>
```

After toggling, it checks whether it now is in the NERDTree buffer. If it is, it jumps back to the previous window.

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Not working. The cursor still remains in the NERDTree window.

Comment: What's the problem? Is the filetype not set, or does the `wincmd p` not work?

Comment: I have no idea, it seems to be the filetype problem. The `wincmd p` command seems to be working.

Comment: Which NERDTree version are you using; how old is it?

Comment: Can confirm that this works with the most recent version of vim and nerdtree.